# Are there any navigation shortcuts for edx courses?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, edx

I'm a passionate user of hotkeys. While using the edX (MOOC Platform) I wish I could use some to navigate between the videos without escaping the wide screen. Since the platform is open source, I wonder if anyone has implemented navigation hotkeys for the webapp?

Comment: As of 2023 that's still not a thing. Source:
https://support.edx.org/hc/en-us